# Fedora restored from cloned image has broken image

Tags: clone, dd, partition-recovery

I`ve had the following issue. Yesterday I`ve dd-ed a HDD with fedora  18 which was split in 3 parts: fedora`s sda1 which was ext4, sda2 which was the LVM and sda3 which was ntfs storage partition. I`ve cloned with `dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sde count 80G` and after the boot, the 80G cloned image had the mounted ntfs partition, which appears to be unmountable and imovable. When I click on it it gaves me: `Error mounting /dev/sda3 at /run/media/ilian/Data: Command-line`mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sda3" "/run/media/ilian/Data"' exited with non-zero exit status 12: Failed to read last sector (468840447): Invalid argument`.
When I`ve opened dev/sda with gparted it reports that it`s unallocated data, and needs a partition table, but creating such will erase the hdd. OK, I don`t mind having the 3rd drive, since nothing is problematic with it - it just stays there and is unaccessible, but is there a way to remove that sda3 partition? cfdisk can`t open it also... so I was thinkig about fsck from my usbbootable rescue linux? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I`ve restored the partition table with sfdisk -d /dev/sda > part.txt, removed the fake partitions then sfdisk /dev/sda < part.txt and everything is normal now :)